# Fileupload - Able to create folder but not save file to it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have a fileupload control triggered by a button. When the button is clicked, I am checking to see if a directory exists, if not then create it and save the file from the fileupload to it. When running the app, if the directory doesn't exist then it gets created successfully, however the file does not save to the directory and throws an unauthorisedaccess exception. I am working on my local machine and the Network Service account has modify permissions to the directory I am creating the sub-directories in. I checked the NTFS permissions on the created folders and they inherit from the parent so that looks ok. Am I doing something wrong in my code or does a different account need permissions to the directory? (I did test by temporarily granting 'Everyone' modify access to the folder but had the same error)

Code:

```
 If fuSupport.HasFile Then

        Dim clockNo As String = lblClockNo.Text.Trim()

        Dim employeePath As String = "~/SupportingFiles/" & clockNo

        If Not Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(employeePath)) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(employeePath))
        End If

        Dim filePath As String = Path.GetFileName(fuSupport.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
        Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(fileName)

        fuSupport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(employeePath))
End if
```

FileUpload Control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSupportingFiles" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>                            
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuSupport" runat="server" Width="100%" /><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUpload" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:50px">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" CssClass="buttonStyle" Text="Upload File" CausesValidation="False" />
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-left:10px">
                                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="upUpload" runat="server">
                                        <ProgressTemplate>
                                            <asp:Image ID="imgAjaxLoader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/APS/Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                                        </ProgressTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                          <br />                        
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: are you an administrator on the machine?

Comment: I am yes. Tried right clicking Visual Studio and selecting 'run as administrator' anyway and still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Amended

```
fuSupport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(employeePath))
```

to

```
fuSupport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(employeePath & "/" & fileName))
```

Now working OK